# график в веб приложении

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, диаграммы, wasm

`Blazor assembly`

посоветуйте пожалуйста какие наборов элементов управления для разработчиков вы знаете, чтоб создавать графики ?
я смотрела у них ⏬ но не нашла, то что мне нужно //может я плохо смотрела...

[Telerik](https://www.telerik.com/blazor-ui)

[DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/blazor/)

[Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/blazor-components)

[Radzen](https://blazor.radzen.com/)

[Infragistics](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-blazor)

[GrapeCity](https://www.grapecity.com/componentone/blazor-ui-controls)

а именно, мне нужно ===> график выдает данные, на него кликаешь он выдает второй и еще раз третий. Поясню. Есть Магазин=статистика===>кликаю как типа аккордеона открывается товары я выбираю
Самый продаваемый товар=статистика===>кликаю и там различные марки товара и такая же схема как аккордеон открывается "подСтатистика"
Самой продаваемой марки=статистика и кнопка собрать все это обратно...

Comment: берете любое решение для JavaScript и вызываете из своего wasm

Comment: @aepot а почему блазор говорит (Blazor — это кроссплатформенная платформа веб-интерфейса с открытым исходным кодом для создания одностраничных приложений с использованием .NET и C# *вместо* JavaScript) ? //а если что какие готовые решения на ```js``` вы знаете с моим запросом ?

Comment: wasm это в браузере же, так? следовательно и js туда тоже можно прикрутить.